# How to keep service active through Powersafe mode

Tags: android, service

I programmed an App for Android and got some trouble with my Service.
The following image may gives a better understanding of the situation. I tried to keep it as simple as possible:

[image: Visualisation of the problem]

I have an Activity that starts a service. This service starts a Thread which does a request to a Web page. As soon as this service is started, it should continue this procedure.
The only Exception is the low memory killer or human request from the activity.

My Problem now: In the moment where the Android-device activates its powersafe-mode (Screen turns black), the Thread is paused/halted. After i reactivate the device, the Thread resumes.

What I got so far:

- Using the emulator, all works fine (sending request even in power safe mode)
- Android-device connected to PC/Laptop (with and without debug mode), all works like it's supposed to be
- Android device not connected to anything --> as soon as it goes to power safe mode, the Thread is pausing
- reactivating the device, the Thread continues (e.g. not destroyed of the low memory killer)

I hope you got an understanding of my problem and can help me. I can't see the reason why it won't work in the one special given situation.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to the [PowerManagement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) class. But use it carefully because :

> Device battery life will be significantly affected by the use of this API. Do not acquire PowerManager.WakeLocks unless you really need them, use the minimum levels possible, and be sure to release them as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi, thanks that solved my problem. I will keep looking more in this topic, since it seems not to be needed if the device is connected to an power source. In that case the safe mode does not deactivate the CPU? Well.. i have to look in this. Thank you anyway :)